# Why does using content_by_lua_block allow nginx location directives to pass through?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am using `openresty/1.15.8.2` as a proxy in front of an application that sometimes needs to accept large-ish files.

I wanted to set `client_max_body_size 200M` conditionally, so only the URL that expects files accepts large body size. The first thing I tried was putting a url check in an if statement like:

```
if ($url ~ /path/to/file/upload) {
    content_max_body_size 200M;
}
```

This doesn't work as nginx says "content_max_body_size" directive not allowed here.

The next thing I tried was a nested location block like so:

```
location ~ ^(mypatterns)$ {
    # do stuff

    location ~ ^/path/for/file/upload$ {
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }

    # do stuff
    proxy_pass whatever;
}
```

This doesnt work, though. I get an error like:

```
*14941 open() "/.../path/for/file/upload" failed (2: No such file or directory), ...
```

This means that the nested location tries to find a file to serve instead of passing through to the rest of the outer location block.

However, if I set an empty `content_by_lua_block {}` directive in the nested location, it works fine:

```
location ~ ^(mypatterns)$ {
    # do stuff

    location ~ ^/path/for/file/upload$ {
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        content_by_lua_block {}
    }

    # do stuff
    proxy_pass whatever;
}
```

Now,

1. only the `/path/for/file/uploads` is allowed a large body size
2. requests that match that path also "pass through" to the rest of the stuff and the `proxy_pass`

It does what I want, but *why*? What's special about invoking a `content_by_lua_block` directive that makes it pass through? How can I make it pass through in vanilla nginx, without `content_by_lua_block`?

Note that if I separate this into two separate non-nested location directives, it still works fine.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/? Sounds like `set_by_lua_block` is what you want